# How can I put the id of the school_year?

Tags: php

My problem is when I save my `student_votes` like this:
[image]

I want that instead of the year will be save I would like to save the id. For an example, if today's year is 2016 then it will be save 2000(because it is the id of the year 2015). The first image is the studentvotes table,
it should be like syearid =2000 if the year is 2015 or if 2016 will be syearid =2001

here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
include('connection/connect.php');
$idnum=$_POST['idnum'];
$stat='voted';
$sqla = "UPDATE student 
      SET status=?
    WHERE idno=?";
$qa = $db->prepare($sqla);
$qa->execute(array($stat,$idnum));

$edittable=$_POST['votes'];
$a=1;
$N = count($edittable);
$YearNow=Date('Y');
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE candidates,student,school_year 
        SET votes=votes+?
        WHERE candid =? AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid  
        AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($a,$edittable[$i]));
    //I think because of this code
    $sqlas = "INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)";
    $qs = $db->prepare($sqlas);
    $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$YearNow));

}

header("location: notification.php?". http_build_query($query));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Need Help guys! thanks

Comment: clarify your question, please, I do not get it.. what you doing, what it's doing now and what it should do?

Comment: what output you need exactly ?

Comment: it should be like syearid =2000 if the year is 2015 or if 2016 will be syearid =2001

Comment: @zeyzey edit your question, please - do not extends comments

Answer (score 0):

I got your question finally:

after:

```
$qa->execute(array($stat,$idnum));
```

put something like: (I am not sure what database layer you use, this is mysqli example)

```
/** @var mysqli $con */
$years = array();
$data = $con->query('SELECT syearid, from_year FROM school_year')->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $row)
  $years[$row['syearid']] = $row['from_year'];
```

and update your

```
$qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$YearNow));
```

to

```
$qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$years[$YearNow]));
```

---

you can also query this after your operations:

```
UPDATE studentvotes AS sv
  JOIN school_year AS sy ON sv.syearid = sy.syearid
  SET sv.syearid = sy.from_year
```

and btw, please, put those preparations above the for loop, main purpose of prepare statements is efficiency

```
$q = $db->prepare("UPDATE candidates,student,school_year 
    SET votes=votes+?
    WHERE candid =? AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow");

$qs = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)");

for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
   $q->execute(array($a, $edittable[$i]));
   $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$YearNow));
}
```

Comment: it's no used because I think because of the line  $qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$YearNow));   The output is the same I want that the output is 2000 tnx

Comment: '$sql1 = mysql_query ("UPDATE studentvotes AS sv
  JOIN school_year AS sy ON sv.syearid = sy.syearid
  SET sv.syearid = sy.from_year");

for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{ $sqlas = "INSERT INTO studentvotes(candid,idno,syearid) VALUES (:m,:n,:o)";
  $qs = $db->prepare($sqlas);
  $years = array();
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT syearid,from_year FROM school_year");
  $rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
   
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
$years[$row['syearid']] = $row['from_year'];
$qs->execute(array(':m'=>$edittable[$i],':n'=>$idnum,':o'=>$years[$YearNow])); nothing's work help

Comment: @zeyzey edit your question.. I am not even trying to decipher this ;)

Comment: @zeyzey there is neither one of my two provided solutions in your code for now.. nothing more I can do for you, sorry. Try what I suggested you..